# iOS curl animation from bottom left to top right

Tags: ios, objective-c, caanimation

I'm trying to achieve animation like turning page vertically from bottom left to top right corner.

I've tried to use CAAnimation but it has mirrored animation (from bottom right to top left).

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
      CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
      [animation setDuration:1.2];
      [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:@"default"]];
      animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
      [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
      animation.startProgress = 0.35;
        [animation setSubtype:@"fromBottom"];
      animation.type = @"pageCurl";
      [self.animatedView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];
}];
```

Changing subtype to "fromLeft" makes animation similar to what I want, but it changes page horizontally instead of vertically.

How I can make required animation flow?

Comment: check this solution for this problem , allow you to use any corner and direction for curl https://github.com/autresphere/ASAnyCurlController

Comment: Thank you @AbdelahadDarwish, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't have an idea that applying transform can change animation way.